# How to send / retrieve Data in Magento Controller, Model and Block

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.4, magento-1.8

I am creating a custom module in Magento. I want to know how to pass data from the `.phtml` file to the Controller and then to the Model.

Just want to know the structure of passing the data in the magento MVC structure.

Comment: Why voted down ... what i did wrong ...i simply ask a question....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple you can call you controller from phtml like

```
Mage::getBaseUrl()/Modulename/Controllername/methodname
```

and to call Model

```
Mage::getModel('modulename/modelname')->methodname()
```

---

Example For controller

```
Mage::getBaseUrl()/priceconfig/index/checkcountryrate?price=$price
```

Where `priceconfig` is my module-name and `index` is my controller name and `checkcountryrate` is my method

Example For Model

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1)
```

***Please first read article about how magento MVC works then you can easily understand***

Let me know if you have any query